# How to downgrade react-native from 0.56.0 to 0.55.4 version?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

Actually I am using **react-native-camera** in my app but it is not working in this version (react-native: 0.56.0) & its working in this version(react-native: 0.55.4).

So now I want to downgrade the react-native: 0.56.0 to react-native: 0.55.4.

My System configuration:
npm 6.1.0,
react-native-cli: 2.0.1,
react-native: 0.56.0,
Mac OS, Xcode 9.3

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So open the file of your project named as `package.json`

Inside it you can find react-native": `"0.56.4"` replace this version with `react-native": "0.55.4"` or whatever the version you want

Then save the file

Go to the terminal or power sell

Rich to your project directory and run the command `npm install`

After installation check the version of react-native by running the command `react-native --version` and make sure that version is which you changed in `package.json`

Restart your project and you are ready to go

Comment: I also had do downgrade `babel-preset-react-native` from 5.x to `4.0.0`.

Comment: @Jay Thummar Thank you it works for me and sorry for lately reply your message

Comment: what about other dependencies? any way to not change it manually?

Comment: how to downgrade other dependency?

Answer (score -1):

Open the file of your project named as package.json

Inside it you will find react-native": "0.56.0" replace this version with react-native": "0.55.4" or the version which you want to change and save the file

go to the terminal or power sell

Go to your project directory and run  command **npm install**

after installation check the version of react-native by running the command **react-native -v** and check that the version  which you changed in package.json is same as the version you get here, then restart your project.